# Not sure where to insert a for loop

Tags: java

I need to code a program that asks the user for the number of spaces between symbols.For eg,

```
&  &  &

&  &  &

&  &  &
```

The user will enter an integer and the spacing between the symbols should change.
I have the following code uptil now:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Spacing 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)

    {
        Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter spaces between stars: ");
        int l=c.nextInt();

        String a="*";
        String b=" ";

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(a+b);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to change the number of symbols and the number of lines.But the problem is how to change the number of spaces.I feel as if there's going to be a for loop involved but I have no clue how to put one in.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do it once.  How would you do this without any looping of any kind?  Then we can build up the looping construct you'd need from there.

Comment: Well...I tried doing that by adding values for b which stores the space.So I just kept on adding b which increased the number of spaces.Is that what you mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need another variable and another for loop

try this one

```
public class Spacing 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter spaces between stars: ");
    int l=c.nextInt();



        String a="*";
        String b=" ";

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a);

             for(int k=0;k<l;k++)
             {
            System.out.print(b);
             }
        }
            System.out.println();
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: 3 is most definitely overkill; I don't think you really need *two*, but I could be taught.

Comment: If you want to: 1- control number of lines 2- control number of characters 3- control space between characters, why in the world 3 loop are wrong???

Comment: When you have too many level of nested loop, it is the time to refactor into a method

Comment: Totally agree, but this si the Solution of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that improves readability and introduces some modularity in your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Spacing {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter spaces between stars: ");
        int numSpaces =scanner.nextInt();
        String charToDisplay = "*";
        String spaces = buildNSpaces(numSpaces);
        int numberOfRows = 3;
        int numberOfCharactersPerRow = 3;

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j < numberOfCharactersPerRow; j++) {
                System.out.print(charToDisplay+spaces);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static String buildNSpaces(final int numSpaces) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < numSpaces; i++) {
            builder.append(" ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i < l;i++)
{
   System.out.print(" ");
}
```

code above will print the number of spaces you input.

so you can use it like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   System.out.print("&");
   for(int j = 0; j < l; j++)
      System.out.print(" ");
}
```

this will print out

`&   &   &` (there's 3 spaces after the last `&` also)
if you input 3 in `l`.